# Excel File Formats/Limits

Tags: php, excel

I am currently using a PHP library called Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer. And the issue I am encountering is that when trying to open a file with multiple sheets (with 200-500 rows) and one with 12500+ records, it gives me a message saying: "We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xls'.Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.". Usually this file contains formats and styling on rows/cells in some of the sheets and then on the 12500+ sheet, the headers has a bit of color. So, I'm trying to find information about Excel that might help checking if I'm hitting a limit and some expressions to make sure I understand the context.

Questions

1)As it pertains to documentation about limitations of Excel file formats, when it states the maximum amount of rows and/or columns allowed, are these boundaries per workbook or per worksheet? For example, if documentation states that the row limit is 65535, is that per worksheet or workbook?

2)What type of behavior can be expected if a file is generated programmatically that exceeds a row or column limitation? Upon opening the file in Excel, is it expected that there will be an error indicating that the file is corrupted if row or column limit is exceeded?

As a note, I know this library is old and that there are newer libraries out there, but due to issues found in the past with memory and others things while trying other libraries, had to keep using this one.

After trying multiple things thinking that it was a encoding issues, invalid characters, format issues, decided to change the version of the BIFF from 5 to 8 within the library code using the setVersion method. However, this method comments say that this method is experimental and only works for version 8 and that it might get deprecated but this make the file generate as expected without the error. So, in order to decide if setting the version as 8 is a good solution, I need to make sure that the reason this is working is because I was hitting a limit and by setting version to 8, that limit is higher now hence the good result.

Comment: Why don't you check the specification? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: `the row limit is 65535`...only if you open the file in Excel 2003 or earlier, which seems an unlikely thing to do.

Comment: `Upon opening the file in Excel, is it expected that there will be an error indicating that the file is corrupted if row or column limit is exceeded`...that seems like a reasonable assumption. You could always try it.

Comment: However if, for some reason, you're still using the old XLS format (which was superseded by XLSX in 2007!), then you may still indeed be limited to 65535 rows per sheet - see answers at https://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx . Again you can try it (those answers suggest a quick way to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of an alternative library for creating XLSX files from php, and when I test my library, I also sometimes encounter this error. It means that the structure of the XLSX file is broken, the library writes some data incorrectly. And this problem can be solved only by making changes to the library itself. Or you will have to change the library.

The only way is to choose another library for generating files. You can try my [FastExcelWriter](https://packagist.org/packages/avadim/fast-excel-writer), it has no problem with memory and it is very fast.